# Is possible to make PopupWindow to be modal, but not as AlertDialog?

Tags: android

Is possible to make PopupWindow to be modal, but not as AlertDialog ?
I  need to put custom layout with custom ok and cancel buttons, sometimes just custom ok button.

Comment: use the Dialog theme thing on your activity, it will be floating, with a dim background over the rest of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a AlertDialog ? You can call `setContentView()` method to customize the dialog view

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom layout with a Dialog Window.

Here's an example.

```
public class Dialog
{
    private static Dialog dlg = null;

    public static void create(Context context, String title, String message, boolean cancelable)
    {
        if (dlg != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        dlg = new Dialog (context);
        dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dlg.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);

        dlg.setContentView(R.layout.help_dialog);

        TextView titleHeader = (TextView)dlg.findViewById(R.id.popup_header_text);
        titleHeader.setText(Html.fromHtml((String) title));

        TextView content = (TextView)dlg.findViewById(R.id.help_content);
        content.setText(Html.fromHtml((String) message));

        Button okBtn = (Button)dlg.findViewById(R.id.help_btn_ok);
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                dismissHelpDialog();
            }
        });

        dlg.setCancelable(cancelable);
        if (cancelable)
        {
            dlg.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        }
        dlg.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) 
            {
                dismissHelpDialog();
            }
        });
        dlg.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) 
            {
                dismissHelpDialog();

            }
        });

        dlg.show();
    }

    private static void dismissHelpDialog()
    {
        if (dlg != null)
        {
            dlg.dismiss();
            dlg = null;
        }
    }
```

And after simply use :

```
Dialog.create(this, "Help Window"), "Help window Text", true);
```